# Java not passing method correclty

Tags: split, readfile

I am having trouble with my program because in the main method I am reading a text file then I use the split method and parse an array. Moreover, I pass it to another method that will manipulate the file but nothing is showing in the terminal. [Txt file to read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQ620.jpg)
Main Method:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line;


    System.out.println ("Please enter the filename to read:");

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (scan.next()));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfex) {
        System.out.println (fnfex.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }

    try {
        String[][] str = new String[7][3];
        int counter =0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null){
            str[counter] = line.split(" "); 
            counter++; 
        }


    int [][] calories = new int [7][3];

    int count =0;
    for (int i =0; i< calories.length; i++){
        for (int j=0; j< calories.length; j++){
            count++;
                calories[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(str[i][j]);
                //System.out.println (str[i][j]  );
        }   

    }

    totCalories(calories);
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Method were I modify the file:
    public static void totCalories (int [][] a){
    int sum =0; 

    for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    for (int j =0; j<a[i].length; j++){
        sum += a[i][j];
    }
    System.out.println ("This is the total number of calories consumed from Monday to Sunday: " + sum);
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you include a sample of the text file?  Also, I see a slight problem with one of your double `for` loops.

Comment: It's missing something?